# Wrong E-Mail sender on order confirmation - Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, order-email, magento-2.2.5

when I receive order confirmations from my shop theres always the wrong sender e-mail adress. It's sending from the main webspace e-mail

[image]

I thought I set the settings correctly but it doesn't seem to work.
The registration-mails work great.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: have you resolve the issue?

Comment: yes. with the answer underneath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a core bug in Magento 2.2.4 & 2.2.5 that impacts the from address on emails. Perhaps this is related? Quick fix is to disable the Amazon_Payment module, clear cache & generated folders (& run di compilation of in production/default mode), and check emails again.

More information on the core bug here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952

Comment: what do you mean with "clear generated folders"?

Comment: It'll be deleting contents of /generated/code and /generated/meta plus running bin/Magento cache:flush from docroot. More info: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

Comment: do i need to recompile? if yes: how?

Comment: Yes, bin/Magento setup:di:compile

Comment: even if i'm in developer mode?

Comment: If you're in developer mode, deleting /generated/code and /generated/meta should be fine, Magento will auto create those files as needed in developer mode.

Comment: You can run this command:
``rm -rf var/* generated/* pub/static/*``

Comment: I have the same issue since 2.2.7, Amazon_Payment module was already disabled. Reclearing the cache doesnt work for me either. Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: @Mike yeah, confirmed it's still present in 2.2.7. There is a commit to the 2.2-develop branch that apparently fixes it (though that says RMA, not orders): https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d196dcc8592a40461cfc797b91b694e8c046d969#diff-dfb3ee5a7f863458afea75f5524cd2e5

This is the magento bug (it's allegedly fixed now though!) https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14952

Comment: @Mike will see if I can take a proper look next week (week commencing 14/01/2019) and will try and post back here. If you get a fix in the meantime, would appreciate the info!